# Why the menu items to edit a specific vocabulary and terms does not show up in administration tool bar?

Tags: 8, configuration, taxonomy-terms

I created a new user with specific role and permissions to CRUD 1 content type and 1 taxonomy vocabular and terms. The thing is that the administration menu item does not show up for the taxonomy pages, logged in as that user i only see the Content tab > Add content > My content type

The user has permissions to adminiter vocabularies and taxonomies and edit/delete terms for its specific vocabulary. Has access to administration toolbar

If i put the URL directly i can edit a term, even create a new one for the specific vocabulary

Do i need to set up another permission?

I'm using admin_toolbar module

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 more permissions as below

1) 'Use the administration pages and help' under System
2) 'Use the administration toolbar' under Toolbar